# Help to solve this congruence

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I need help to prove this congruence:

$$ 3^n -4(2^n) + 6(1^n) + (-1)^n \equiv 0 \pmod {24} $$

I have tried to used Euler's Theorem on the powers of 2 and 3 individually but now I'm stuck.

Comment: wait I think I made a mistake. I will edit

Answer (score 1):

As revised, it's still not true for $n=0$. However, it is true for all positive integers $n$, so assume that $n\ge 1$.

HINT: Try proving by induction that $3^n\equiv 3\pmod{24}$ when $n$ is odd, and $3^n\equiv 9\pmod{24}$ when $n$ is even. Then discover and prove a similar result for $4(2^n)$. Then put the pieces together

Answer (score 1):

${\rm mod}\ 3\!:\ f(n) \equiv 2^n - 2^n\equiv 0\ $ for $\,n\ge 1$

${\rm mod}\ 8\!:\ f(n)\equiv 3^n+(-1)^n+6,\,$ for $\,n\ge 1.\ $  $\,f(1)\equiv 0\equiv f(2),\,$ and $\,f(n+2)\equiv f(n)\,$ by $\,3^2\equiv 1\equiv (-1)^2,\,$ so $\,f(n)\equiv 0\,$ for all $\,n\ge 1\,$ by induction.

Therefore $\ 3,8\mid f(n)\,\Rightarrow\, 24={\rm lcm}(3,8)\mid f(n)\ $ for $\,n\ge 1$

Answer (score 0):

For $n = 2$ you have $9 - 4 * 4 + 6 + 17 = 16 \equiv 16 \mod 24$ so the expression doesn't seem to be true.